# twentysecondcv set computer modern as default font

Tags: fonts, texmaker, computer-modern

I would like to set the Computer Modern font (as far as I know it is the default font of the article class) as the default font in the twentysecondcv template. The relevant files can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex.git). Personally, I only work in the `twentyseconds.cls` and `Twenty-Seconds_cv.tex` files. I suspect that the relevant changes have to be done in `twentyseconds.cls` but am not sure.

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: In the .cls file, comment the line 23: `\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}`

Comment: This is correct. If you answer the question I could mark it as answered, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the class file you are referring to is loading the ClearSans package and setting it as the default font.

Commenting the line in the .CLS file disables it and you will end up using Computer Modern again.

```
\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
```

However you can restore Computer Modern defaults (assuming you are using pdfLaTeX and not `fontspec`) with:

```
\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt}
```

Or if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (Latin Modern defaults instead of Computer Modern)

```
\renewcommand\rmdefault{lmr}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{lmss}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}
```